# IdentityServer4 - tutorial Quickstart - User does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm quite new in the IdentityServer stuff and a C# beginner. I'm trying the first tutorial on the IdentityServer4 page
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html
Having written the solution, I still have an error on this code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
}
```

It says "The name User does not exist in the current context.
Which make sense since there is no variable or class named 'User'. BUT, there's nothing on the sort in the tutorial either, and when I look the controller file on github, there is no 'using' I don't have that could explain this 'User'.
So my question is: what is supposed to be the 'User' in this example and how can I eliminate this error and make this work?

Comment: User is a property on the base class ControllerBase. Maybe you forgot to have your class inherit from ControllerBase?

Comment: Did you get method exist in a controller which inherit from `Controller` or `ControllerBase`?Any way,you could also inject IHttpContextAccessor to get the User.

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial you are mentioning, the Get() entry point is protected by an "[Authorize]" that will challenge the default authentication scheme which should trigger the authentication and come back to your entry point with an authenticated user that will then have the proper claims defined. Here, no authentication took place.